# CreatePipe succeeds but does not generate a valid pair of handles

Tags: winapi, pipe, vba7

I am writing some VBA code, and I want to be able to spawn a child process and communicate with it via stdin/stdout. I found a description of how to do this in C/C++ here:

[Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output)

I am using Microsoft's VBA bindings for kernel functions as found here:

[Office 2010 Help Files: Win32API_PtrSafe with 64-bit Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/office-suite-issues/win32api_ptrsafe-with-64-bit-support)

Having started to port the C/C++ example to VBA, I have the code below, which only creates the pipe and nothing more. It checks that the operation succeeded and prints the handles that `CreatePipe()` outputs.

```vb
Sub test_pipe_creation()
    ' Security attribute structure
    Dim secAttrStdHand As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    secAttrStdHand.nLength = Len(secAttrStdHand)
    secAttrStdHand.bInheritHandle = True
    secAttrStdHand.lpSecurityDescriptor = 0
    
    ' The handles
    Dim stdout_r As Long
    Dim stdout_w As Long
    stdout_r = &HDEADBEEF ' initialised to an obviously incorrect handle
    stdout_w = &HDEADBEEF

    Dim res As Long
    Dim e As Long
    
    Debug.Print "About to create pipe, handles currently have dummy values", Hex(stdout_r), Hex(stdout_w)
    
    ' Try to create the pipe
    res = CreatePipe(VarPtr(stdout_r), VarPtr(stdout_w), secAttrStdHand, 0)
    If res = 0 Then
        e = GetLastError
        Debug.Print "Failed to create pipe"
        Debug.Print "Error: ", e
    Else
        Debug.Print "Pipe created"
    End If
    
    Debug.Print "Pipe handle values are:", Hex(stdout_r), Hex(stdout_w)
    
End Sub
```

When I run this, I get the following output:

```
About to create pipe, handles currently have dummy values             DEADBEEF      DEADBEEF
Pipe created
Pipe handle values are:     DEADBEEF      DEADBEEF
```

So this means that `CreatePipe()` returned `True` indicating success, but it did not update the handle variables `stdout_r` and `stdout_w`.

To be sure that it wasn't just that the return code was wrong, I did also try checking the error code with `GetLastError()` regardless of the return code. The error value reported is `0` which indicates success, so Windows is definitely reporting that the operation succeeded.

What causes this behaviour? How can I create a pipe correctly from VBA code?

(Windows 11, Word, not sure which version of Word as it's not obvious how to check, but I just installed it recently along with the rest of Office 365)

Comment: What does your declaration of `CreatePipe()` look like? Sounds like you are not passing the memory addresses of your variables correctly.

Comment: I am using the declaration that is provided by microsoft, it looks like this: `Declare PtrSafe Function CreatePipe Lib "kernel32" (phReadPipe As LongPtr, phWritePipe As LongPtr, lpPipeAttributes As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, ByVal nSize As Long) As Long`

Comment: The first two parameters are ByRef LongPtr.  The declarations for stdout_r and stdout_w are wrong, need to be LongPtr.  Don't use VarPtr()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, VBA passes parameters *by reference*, unless `ByVal` is specified (as you are doing in the `nSize` parameter).

`VarPtr()` returns a `LongPtr`, and you are declaring the `phReadPipe` and `phWritePipe` parameters of `CreatePipe()` as taking `LongPtr` *by reference*. So, you are actually passing `CreatePipe()` the addresses of the temporary `LongPtr`s that `VarPtr()` returns, not the addresses of your `Long` variables <sup>1</sup> that `VarPtr()` is pointing at.

<sup>1</sup>: which BTW, should be declared as `LongPtr` instead of `Long`, as Win32 `HANDLE`s are pointers, not integers.

That is why `CreatePipe()` is not modifying your variables.  It is instead modifying the temporary `LongPtr`s from `VarPtr()`.  You can easily verify that using explicit variables, eg:

```vb
Dim temp1 as LongPtr
Dim temp2 as LongPtr

...

temp1 = VarPtr(stdout_r)
temp2 = VarPtr(stdout_w)

Debug.Print "Pipe handle addresses are:", Hex(temp1), Hex(temp2)

res = CreatePipe(temp1, temp2, secAttrStdHand, 0)
' temp1 and temp2 get modified!

Debug.Print "Pipe handle addresses are:", Hex(temp1), Hex(temp2)
```

To solve that, try adding `ByVal` to the 1st two parameters, eg:

```vb
Declare PtrSafe Function CreatePipe Lib "kernel32" (ByVal phReadPipe As LongPtr, ByVal phWritePipe As LongPtr, lpPipeAttributes As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, ByVal nSize As Long) As Long
```

Alternatively, drop the `VarPtr()` altogether and just use `ByRef` instead:

```vb
Declare PtrSafe Function CreatePipe Lib "kernel32" (ByRef phReadPipe As Long, ByRef phWritePipe As Long, lpPipeAttributes As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, ByVal nSize As Long) As Long
...
res = CreatePipe(stdout_r, stdout_w, secAttrStdHand, 0)
```

Either way, `CreatePipe()` should now receive the addresses of your `Long` <sup>1</sup> variables.